# Error en el bucle con funciones

Tags: python, funciones, bucles

Hola he estado programando utilizando funciones pero tengo un error desde hace rato

> 3. Construir una función que reciba como parámetro un entero y retorne la cantidad de dígitos.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def main():
    try:
        cont = 0
        numero = int(input('Ingrese un número entero: '))
        digito = cont_digitos(numero)
        print('El número ingresado es de',cont,'digitos')
        
    except ValueError:
        print('Dato invalido')
from funciones import cont_digitos
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Y en la funcion importada `cont_digitos` el codigo es el siguiente:

```
    def cont_digitos(numero):
    global cont
    while numero >= 10:
        numero //= 10
        cont += 1
```

el error esta en cuando entra al ciclo.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Proyectos/Python/Python funciones/Ejercicio3.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:/Proyectos/Python/Python funciones/Ejercicio3.py", line 8, in main
    digito = cont_digitos(numero)
  File "d:\Proyectos\Python\Python funciones\funciones.py", line 20, in cont_digitos
    cont += 1
NameError: name 'cont' is not defined
```

me sale este error y no se el porque si la variable esta definida en la funcion `main()` y menos el error de `main()` y de `cont_digitos()`

Comment: Tienes que asignar algo a `cont` fuera de todas las otras funciones. Por ejemplo, `cont=0` justo antes de `def main()`. Las definiciones que tienes son declaraciones internas a la función, no globales.

Answer (score 0):

no te compliques mucho, aqui hay un ejemplo de una funcion que hace lo que necesitas

```
def count_digitos(num : int) -> int:
    num=str(num)
    return(len(num))
```

transformas el digito a tipo String y utilizas la funcion len() para retornar el numero de caracteres.